# How to customize Bulma?

Tags: sass, customization, bulma

I want to customize Bulma.
I read the document https://bulma.io/documentation/overview/customize/
but I cannot understand.

1. npm install bulma
2. cd node_modules/bulma
3. mv bulma.sass bulma.sass.org
4. vi bulma.sass
5. pasted Set your variables code and save named bulma.sass
6. npm run build-sass

and build error.

please teach me how to ?

Comment: What part are you stuck on?

Comment: I 'm trying changed pasted code to save sass directory.

Comment: And edit package.json to point to changed path like that

Comment: "hoge": "node-sass --output-style expanded --source-map true ./sass/hoge.sass css/bulma.css",

Comment: npm run hoge but exit1

Answer (score 3):

First, the best way is not to change the node_module's file content.

The simplest way is to create custom scss file and include Bulma SCSS into it.

```
@charset "utf-8";
// modify the bulma variables here
$primary: #404BFF;
$navbar-item-img-max-height: 5rem;
$card-header-background-color: $primary;
$card-header-color: white;
$footer-background-color: $primary;
$footer-color: white;
// Import Bulma and Buefy styles
@import "~bulma"; // or fallow the partial import example from docs.

// add custom css here.
```

Comment: Where do you put this custom scss file so that your project knows it exists?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [this](https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/with-node-sass/) is the page you need.

Otherwise, if you've installed `sass` you might choose to follow this step: I'm no `npm` expert so I chose to download Bulma, create a custom `.sass` file and let sass generate my css. This path is explained here: https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/with-sass-cli/

Comment: Is it necessary to use sass ? Cant we just create our css file and override from that ?

Answer (score 2):

This may be bad form but if you write your own css in the html file, you can add `!important` to override the bulma colors.
i.e. if there's a button color you don't like such as `is-primary` you can do `background-color: blue !important`.

Just try not to use `!important` all over the place.

The better solution would be to download sass -- but I can't help with that. The other answer should help?

Comment: I do not thing that this is a good case to apply !impportant in here.

Comment: the more styles you wil try to override the more !important cases you will have to apply.

Answer (score 1):

I discover that if you set an `id="for-example"` for a div and then you go to your styles.scss you can create a new class for that `id.div` like this:

```
#for-example {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

I don't know if is a bad practice but it works for me!